# Glossy material affecting color of another objects

Tags: cycles-render-engine, color

I need to make this blue vectors appears blue inside this orange material.

In other words, how I can "preserve" material color from color interferences of another objects?

I'm using cycles render.

Thank you very much. [image]

I made the steps proposed and achieved this result:

[image]

Comment: give it an Emission node instead of a DIffuse?

Answer (score 3):

Edit:

My bad, your cube is actually opaque, which was hard to guess from the pictures, I don't know if it's feasible with the *Light Path* node (?) so, as Thedigitalzorn said, the solution is probably to use the *Compositor*.

Another simple trick would be to launch a render of the arrow only, in the *Properties* panel > *Render > Film*, enable *Transparent* to make sure that the video has a transparent background. Then render the cube and the setup. At last, stack the 2 sequences in the *Video Sequencer*.

Old answer:

Give your arrow an *Emission* node instead of a Diffuse. And if you don't want it to emit any light, deactivate its *Diffuse* option in the *Properties* panel > *Object > Visibility*.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you. But it's works because this cube is not color, correct? I followed this same steps and the result is different.

Comment: in what way is it different?

Comment: I don't know how to attach images in comments, so I will edit my post.

Comment: hard to understand what happes, do you mean you want the object to always be seen through any object?

Comment: I'm sorry for my explanation.Please, look the second image in edition of this post. Please, look at the blue cylinder outside of orange block. This cylinder have the same color of the arrows inside the orange block.

I would like to make arrows inside the orange block appears blue like the blue cylinder outside.

Comment: still hard to understand, could you please make a larger screenshot or share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Thank you. https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/s8vapPLL/

Comment: it was hard to understand that your box was actually half opaque, so it's normal that any object inside will appear colored... like thedigitalzorn says, I think you'll have to fix that through the Compositor editor, I don't know enough about it though

Answer (score 0):

If the arrow has a solid color, you could use a cryptomatte to isolate the silhouette and give it a color using the compositing nodes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I didn't find cryptomatte in node editor. I'm using blender 2.8.